# Convert byte array represented as string to byte array

Tags: arrays, string, go

I have a `byte` array represented in the form of a `string` like so:

```
inputString := "[16 2 26 25 82 101 108 101 97 115 101 32 97 114 116 105 102 97 99 116 115 32 102 101 116 99 104 101 100 32 60 42 6 8 149 188 185 251 5]"
```

I wish to be able to convert this string into an array of bytes exactly the way it's represented:

```
desiredResult := []byte{16, 2, 26, 25, 82, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 32, 97, 114, 116, 105, 102, 97, 99, 116, 115, 32, 102, 101, 116, 99, 104, 101, 100, 32, 60, 42, 6, 8, 149, 188, 185, 251, 5}
```

How can I do this in Go?

Comment: Replace spaces with commas, then JSON Unmarshall it to a `[]byte` https://play.golang.org/p/eRWEWrgseHW

Comment: Your desired result is a slice, not an array.

Comment: More important: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```golang
    inputString := "[16 2 26 25 82 101 108 101 97 115 101 32 97 114 116 105 102 97 99 116 115 32 102 101 116 99 104 101 100 32 60 42 6 8 149 188 185 251 5]"
    desiredResult := []byte{}
    
    inputString = strings.Trim(inputString, "[]")
    for _, i := range strings.Split(inputString, " ") {
        j, err := strconv.Atoi(i)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        desiredResult = append(desiredResult, byte(j))
    }
    fmt.Println(desiredResult)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3na_sC3oMeY)